# iOS Cordova app doesn't load correctly on device

Tags: html, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

Having a problem starting my Cordova app on an iPad.
The build works fine (after adding some missing Frameworks and removing the arm64 from the Valid Architecture in the Build Settings).

When the app starts everything seems to work fine. Splash screen is shown and I get the console output in Xcode:

```
[565:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
[565:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
[565:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
```

then nothing happens for a long time. Only a grey background is shown.
After some time (about 20-30 seconds) the index.html seems to get loaded due to the console log:

```
[584:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/64C4D056-619D-46F9-96E4-EAC7E11DBA15/E-Mail%20Acquisition.app/www/index.html
```

the screen changes to a different grey value (assuming its the index.html background) but that's it.

I assume it has to do something with the build settings in Xcode since it runs on one device but not the other. When archived and installed (so not starting with Xcode) it doesn't work on both devices... Any idea what is going wrong here?

Some images for illustration:

How it looks after index.html gets loaded with the error:
[image]

How it looks after index.html gets loaded without the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found out where my problem was. When trying to install it on an android platform I found out something was wrong with my page slider files in my utils folder.

After overwriting it with an older version it works like a charm. Sorry I can't give any exact explanation what was exactly causing that error but maybe this will help someone anyhow messing with the same problem.